# Mergesort Conditional Jump error

Tags: c, valgrind, mergesort

I'm having trouble tracking down a "conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" valgrind error in some mergesort code I wrote.  The code sorts things properly, but I know there's a memory leak from a variable not being initialized.  Valgrind tells me it's in the m_sort portion of my code, but I'm not sure what's not being initialized.

```
void merge(int *C, int *A, int n, int *B, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0,j=0,k=0; k<(n+m); k++) {
        if (i==n) {
            C[k] = B[j];
            j++;
        }
        else if (j==m) {
            C[k] = A[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
              if (A[i] < B[j]) {
                 C[k] = A[i];
                 i++;
          }
              else {
                 C[k] = B[j];
                 j++;
          }
       }
    }
}

void m_sort(int *A, int *B, int left, int right) {
    int mid;
    if (right >left) {
        mid =((right + left)/2);
        m_sort(B, A, left, mid);
        m_sort(B, A, mid+1, right);
        merge(A+left, B+left, mid-left+1, B+mid+1, right-mid);
    }
}

void merge_sort(int *a, int left, int right)
{
    int * T = NULL;
  int i;
    T = (int*)malloc((right+1)*sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<right; i++) 
    {
        T[i] = a[i];
    }
    m_sort(a,T,left,right);
  free(T);
}
```

Comment: You can find out where uninitialised data comes from with `--track-origins=yes`. Have you tried that?

Comment: You allocate `right + 1` number of integers for `T` in the `merge_sort` function, but you only initialize `right` number of elements in the array. Also, if you build with debug information then Valgrind will happily provide file and function names, as well as line number.

Comment: I tracked it down using your guys' advice, thank you!  It was in my malloc.